# React Ionic Image is not working when sending parameter as array attribute

Tags: reactjs, image, ionic-framework

I am trying to use a slide that shows products attributes in my app.

The products variable has the ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, PRICE and IMAGE.

```
const products = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Sapato1",
  description: "comfort line with adaptive design",
  price: "999,99",
  img: "../img/hamburger1.jpg"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Product X",
  description: "Different sizes and shapes",
  price: "999,99",
  img: "../img/hamburger2.jpg"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "Product Y",
  description: "Many different features",
  price: "999,99",
  img: "../img/hamburger3.jpg"
}]
```

Using HTML img tag with an import it is working, but I would like to have the image related to the product I am showing, as variable.

```
import Image from '../img/hamburger1.jpg';

<img src={Image} alt="produt1" />
```

but I would like to use src={product.img} instead of the src={Image} but it is not working.

This is the code I am using

```
{products.map((product) =>
          <IonSlide>
            <IonCard button={true}>
              <IonCardHeader>
                <IonCardTitle>{product.name}</IonCardTitle>
                <IonCardSubtitle>Card Subtitle</IonCardSubtitle>
              </IonCardHeader>

              <IonCardContent>
                <img src={Image} alt="produt1" />
                {product.description}
              </IonCardContent>
              <IonButton expand="full" href="#" color="primary"><IonIcon slot="start" icon={cart} />R$ {product.price}</IonButton>
            </IonCard>
          </IonSlide>
        )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your `img` folder along with all the pictures in the `public` folder. And then you can change your references to the images like `img: "/img/hamburger1.jpg"`. That should work. Here's a working example - https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-golick-funtz?file=/src/App.js